# Apache redirect if there are two directories in URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a site where there are user accounts and pages for the public.

I would like to be able to access a users account with a URL like

```
http://mySite/theUserName
```

and access the back pages with

```
http://mysite/page/pageName
```

I have a RewriteRule currently that looks like this which works for redirecting the page.

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/? /application/pages/getPage.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

How ever if you try and access a user account it still runs the rule as the rule doesn't know a page name was not given.

So how do I run the rule only if both "page" and "pageName" are provided and ignore it otherwise.

I guess another way that would not be as clean but would work is only run the rule if the first directory is "page"

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I would put a "/" at the beginning...like RewriteRule ^/page/(.*)/? /application/pages/getPage.php?page=$1 [NC,L] ... unless theUserName is "page" it should do what you ask

Comment: Hmm, that simple?

What I have now is 
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /getPage.php?type=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /getPage.php?type=$1 [NC,L]
and I moved getPage.php to the public and will do the handling there. What do you think?

Comment: Well...looks like you're redirecting essentially everything to getPage.php....would probably prefer something like ^/(.+)/(.+)/?$ /getPage.php?type=$1&page=$2 ...easier to read but that's just me. That said, non-alpha would go through.